# Creating a table with super columns and rows

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

After attempts with little success, I can't seem to achieve the table depicted by the image below. The image demonstrates the format I wish to achieve, to which I will add more columns and rows to eventually. If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be highly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Pretty simple, because all text is on _one_  horitontal line. Use `\multicolumn`, that's all ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enjoy (though all those rules don't look good):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newcommand\mc{\multicolumn}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[]{|ll|*6{c|}}
  \cline{3-8}
  \mc{1}{l}{}&&\mc{3}{|c|}{Col 1}&\mc{3}{c|}{Col 2}\\
  \cline{3-8}
  \mc{1}{l}{}&& \mc{1}{c}{C} & \mc{1}{c}{NC} & \mc{1}{c|}{SR} 
              & \mc{1}{c}{C} & \mc{1}{c}{NC} & \mc{1}{c|}{SR} \\
  \hline
    & Ex 1 &&&&&&\\
  \cline{3-8}
  Row 1& Ex 2 &&&&&&\\
  \cline{3-8}
    & Ex 3 &&&&&&\\
  \hline
    & Ex 1 &&&&&&\\
  \cline{3-8}
  Row 2& Ex 2 &&&&&&\\
  \cline{3-8}
    & Ex 3 &&&&&&\\
  \hline
    & Ex 1 &&&&&&\\
  \cline{3-8}
  Row 3& Ex 2 &&&&&&\\
  \cline{3-8}
    & Ex 3 &&&&&&\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]